# unable to get session data in laravel

Tags: php, session, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I am using laravel 5.1 when I created session through ajax-login method name (signinuser) it created session. I can put and get Session. 
Other hand When I try to get session data from anther method(userprofile) from same controller, session data disappear

Below my Controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use DB;
use Auth;
Use Session;
Use View;
Use Crypt;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class HomeController extends Controller {

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Home Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller renders your application's "dashboard" for users that
    | are authenticated. Of course, you are free to change or remove the
    | controller as you wish. It is just here to get your app started!
    |
    */

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //$this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard to the user.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

        return view('index');
    }

    public function signupuser(){
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
        $usrname   = ($data->uname);
        $upswd     = ($data->pswd);
        $uemail    = ($data->email);
        $validUser = true;
        $userEmail = DB::table('users')->where('email', $uemail)->first();
        if(empty($userEmail)){
            $userName = DB::table('users')->where('username', $usrname)->first();

            if(!empty($userName)){
                $arr = array('msg' => "", 'error' => 'User Already exists with same username','action'=>'exist');
                $validUser =false;

            }
        }else{
            $arr = array('msg' => "", 'error' => 'User Already exists with same email','action'=>'exist');
            $validUser =false;
        }

        if ($validUser) {
            $encrypted = md5($upswd);
            $id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId(
                                                    [
                                                        'username' => $usrname,
                                                        'email'    => $uemail,
                                                        'password' => $encrypted,
                                                        'last_login' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                                                        'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                                                    ]
                                                   );

            if ($id) {
                $sql ="select * from users where id=$id"; 
                $users = DB::select($sql);
                Session::put('userinfo',$users[0]);
                $arr = array('msg' => "User Created Successfully!!!", 'error' => '','action'=>'insert');

            } else {
                $arr = array('msg' => "", 'error' => 'Error In inserting record','action'=>'error in inserting');

            }
        } 
        $jsn = json_encode($arr);
        print_r($jsn);
        exit;
    }
    public function signinuser(){
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
        $usrname = ($data->uname);
        $upswd   = ($data->pswd);
        $pwd     = md5($upswd);
        $sql ="select * from users where password='$pwd' AND (email='$usrname' OR username='$usrname')"; 
        $users = DB::select($sql);

        if(empty($users)){
            $arr = array('msg' => "", 'error' => 'Please enter valid username or email.','action'=>'error');
        }else{
            Session::put('userinfo',$users[0]);

            DB::table('users')
            ->where('id', $users[0]->id)
            ->update(['last_login' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
            $arr = array('msg' => "Login successfully.", 'error' => '','action'=>'success');
        }
        $sessiondata = Session::all();
        echo '<pre>==='; print_r($sessiondata); exit; 
        $jsn = json_encode($arr);
        print_r($jsn);
        exit;

    }

    public function userprofile(){

        Session::put('key', 'pankaj');
        $value = Session::get('key');
        $sessiondata = Session::all();
        echo '<pre>==='.$value; print_r($sessiondata); exit; 
         return View::make('profile', $data);

    }

}
?>
```

> signinuser method(ajax call) response

```
Array
(
    [_token] => cOCcWvyy8Z93W36rpaNNjU4p2cmC2l5t75WT0LaH
    [_previous] => Array
        (
            [url] => http://laravel.example.com
        )

    [flash] => Array
        (
            [old] => Array
                (
                )

            [new] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [userinfo] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 8
            [email] => pankaj@mail.com
            [username] => pancaz
            [avatar] => 
            [password] => e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e
            [permissions] => 
            [last_login] => 2015-11-04 06:26:28
            [first_name] => 
            [last_name] => 
            [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [updated_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        )

)
```

> other method hit url (http://localhost/project/home/profile)

```
Array
(
    [_token] => cOCcWvyy8Z93W36rpaNNjU4p2cmC2l5t75WT0LaH
    [_previous] => Array
        (
            [url] => http://laravel.example.com
        )

    [flash] => Array
        (
            [old] => Array
                (
                )

            [new] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [key] => pankaj
)
```

> ```
> routes.php file path app/Http/routes.php contains
> ```

```
Route::post('home/signupuser', 'HomeController@signupuser');
Route::post('home/signinuser', 'HomeController@signinuser');

Route::get('home/profile', 'HomeController@userprofile');
```